# Ruby on Rails: How to debug xml API call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi Friends,
I am trying to create an XML API for my sample application.. I am seeing GET request is fine with status code 200 OK. In case of POST and PUT methods I am seeing the object is not created with given data.
Meaning when I do POST request with input

> Metonymy
>       10
>       4

the output is

> 19         
>   2015-06-05T01:41:50Z
>   2015-06-05T01:41:50Z

If we see output the name, price and category are empty. I do not understand reason for this.

My Questions are

1) Why it is not taking all the data I gave?

2) What is the way to track payload inside controller

The headers are Accept: application/xml Content-Type: application/xml
Thanks in advance..

Comment: My controller code is 
module Api
 module V1
   class ProductsController < ApplicationController
     skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
     respond_to :xml
    def index
   respond_with Product.all
    end
    def create
   respond_with Product.create(params[:product])
    end
   def show
  respond_with Product.find(params[:id])
   end
   def update
  respond_with Product.update(params[:product])
   end 
     end
 end
end